# spring-aop On apple silicon (M1) : Illegal method name

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-aop, apple-m1

My working project uses kotlin + spring-boot.

I found this issue when I try to run a test case having space like `should success WHEN setting key is api updatable` on the MacBook `apple-m1` machine.

Example

```
@Test
@Transactional
fun `should success when setting key is api updatable`()
```

Then JVM throw Exception that contains stack trace looks like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal method name "should success when setting key is api updatable" in class com/xxx/xxx/web/rest/CompanySettingResourceIntTest$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0902682
```

This happens on my MacBook m1 machine but never happens on the intel machine.

I try to investigate this issue, then I found when using `@Transactional` on the method in bean, `spring-aop` will create a proxy class by using method `java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass`.

I have a lot of methods that look like this and it's easy to read. Can I use a method name that contains `space` run in the m1 machine, How do I fix it?

Thank you.

---

Environment

- JDK version 1.8 (AArch64)
- Spring boot 1.5.16
- JUnit 4

(I try to POC using spring-boot2+JUnit5 test-case name contains space is fine. But a method in beans throws the `Illegal method name` too.)

---

JUnit log (Run test)

```
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.xxx.xxx.web.rest.CompanySettingResourceIntTest: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.xxx.xxx.web.rest.CompanySettingResourceIntTest: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:466)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:349)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$100(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:201)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:459)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal method name "should success when setting key is api updatable" in class com/xxx/xxx/web/rest/CompanySettingResourceIntTest$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0902682
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    ... 91 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be hitting [Spring issue #21674](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21674) which was fixed in Spring 5.1. You might want to upgrade, if that is an option. It seems there is a fix which ignores those kinds of methods. If that is OK for you or not, I do not know.

Some background information: Your target method is transactional, so Spring tries to create a CGLIB proxy for it. I quickly verified in a simple Spock (Groovy) test that CGLIB seems to be unable to handle methods containing spaces correctly -probably because it is simply unaware of languages like Groovy and Kotlin which allow such things. Here is a proof of concept. I used Groovy and Spock, because I am lazy and did not want to set up a Kotlin project. But I am expecting the result to be identical.

**Java class under test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70654015;

public class SampleJava {
  public String greet(String input) {
    return "Hello " + input + "!";
  }
}
```

**Groovy class under test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70654015

class SampleGroovy {
  String "say hello to"(String input) {
    "Hello $input!"
  }
}
```

**Spock test creating CGLIB proxies:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70654015

import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor
import spock.lang.Specification

class CGLIBProxyTest extends Specification {
  def "create CGLIB proxy for Java class"() {
    given:
    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer()
    enhancer.superclass = SampleJava
    enhancer.callback = { obj, method, args, proxy ->
      method.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class && method.getReturnType() == String.class
        ? "Hello cglib!"
        : proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args)
    } as MethodInterceptor

    when:
    SampleJava proxy = enhancer.create()

    then:
    proxy.greet("world") == "Hello cglib!"
  }

  def "create CGLIB proxy for Groovy class with spaces in method name"() {
    given:
    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer()
    enhancer.superclass = SampleGroovy
    enhancer.callback = { obj, method, args, proxy ->
      method.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class && method.getReturnType() == String.class
        ? "Hello cglib!"
        : proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args)
    } as MethodInterceptor

    when:
    SampleGroovy proxy = enhancer.create()

    then:
    proxy."say hello to"("world") == "Hello cglib!"
  }
}
```

The first test passes, the second one fails with:

```
net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:345)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:305)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70654015.CGLIBProxyTest.create CGLIB proxy for Groovy class with spaces in method name(CGLIBProxyTest.groovy:36)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:459)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal method name "say hello to" in class de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q70654015/SampleGroovy$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ef703cf1
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    ... 14 more
```

This is the same error you experieced. As soon as you rename the Groovy method to something which is legal in a JVM, the test passes.

With regard to your claim that the behaviour is supposed to be dependent on the hardware or OS platform, I disagree. I think you probably have differences in your runtime environment. How are you building and running your project? Maven, Gradle, something else?

---

**Update:** I have good news for you: I had run my test on JDK 8 and 15 and `cglib:cglib-nodep:3.2.6`. When upgrading to CGLIB 3.3.0, the test started passing. So you might want to version-manage CGLIB in your Maven POM's `<dependencyManagement>` section (or whatever is Gradle's equivalent) to that version. Maybe it helps. Please note that some tools might also depend on `cglib:cglib`, so you want to version-manage that one too. I.e., make sure that you use these versions:

- `cglib:cglib-nodep:3.3.0`
- `cglib:cglib:3.3.0` (if it is used in your application)

---

**Update 2:** I am not a regular Spring user, so I forgot that Spring Core (artifact `org.springframework:spring-core`) includes its own CGLIB version, relocated to base package name `org.springframework.cglib`. Please note the package name difference from your stack trace to the original `net.sf.cglib` for my stand-alone example.

I checked for you and found out that since version `5.2.0.RELEASE`, Spring Core was [upgraded to CGLIB 3.3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/4123910d3df3e22d5398f361eea8676755652f4e). So if you can use a Spring version 5.2.0 or more recent, chances are that it works for you.

Comment: **Update:** CGLIB 3.3.0 handles method names with spaces correctly. I also updated my answer.

Comment: **Update 2:** In order go upgrade to CGLIB 3.3.0 inside Spring Core, upgrade the latter to version 5.2.0.RELEASE or more recent. See also my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @kriegaex.

I try to update another project in my company (use spring-boot 2.19.0) to 2.2.0 (spring-core 5.2) it works.

but the core project (spring-4) is hard to migrate because it's a legacy project that much depends on a lot of libraries, tools, configuration.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Then for your legacy project, better use canonical method names in your tests, if you don't want to migrate just because of spaces in test methods.